# beautifulsoup configure autoclosing tags

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

Let's explain my issue by example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                                                                                                    

txt = """                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
<body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
<ul>
    <li> 1
    <li> 2
</ul>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Here output of this script:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li>
    1
    <li>
     2
    </li>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the input html `li` tags were not closed. BeautifulSoup fixed it in some way. But is it possible to configure BeautifulSoup to get this result on the output?

```
<html>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li>
    1
   </li>
   <li>
     2
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'fixing' is applied by the *parser* used to load the HTML into the BeautifulSoup object tree.

You can swap out different parsers; broken HTML is repaired in different ways by different parsers. You'll have to [install additional packages](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser); by default only the `html.parser` option is available.

I'd use the `html5lib` parser here, it'll interpret non-standard HTML the same way a browser would, or you can try the `lxml` parser:

```
>>> print BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html5lib').prettify()
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li>
    1
   </li>
   <li>
    2
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
>>> print BeautifulSoup(txt, 'lxml').prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li>
    1
   </li>
   <li>
    2
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, both these produce the desired output.

It's only the default parser that exhibits this problem:

```
>>> print BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser').prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li>
    1
    <li>
     2
    </li>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```